# "Installation or uninstallation is not working temporarily" error when trying to launch Tizen watch application from Tizen SDK

Tags: eclipse, tizen, tizen-native-app

When trying to launch the native watch application from Tizen IDE, I see the strange message "Certain application categories, such as "Watch Application", cannot be launched by "Run As".

Indeed, I try to use Run As from the project local menu to launch my app. But how else I am supposed to launch my application on the emulator?

The emulator device (watch) is up and running, visible on desktop as a separate widget. It is selected. The signing configuration is set up.

On the console output I see the message `processing result : FATAL_ERROR [61]`.

I also tried to launch through the created launch configuration but this results the same error message.

The IDE logs show the following stack trace:

```
[2015.09.06 12:16:48][ERROR] ConnectionExplorer.java(658) - Fail to get platform log
[2015.09.06 12:18:59][ERROR] RdsDeployer.java(269) - Cannot partially upload or reinstall
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: [RDS] Cannot install application
    at org.tizen.common.rds.RdsDeployer.newCoreException(RdsDeployer.java:699)
    at org.tizen.common.rds.RdsDeployer.postInstall(RdsDeployer.java:634)
    at org.tizen.common.rds.RdsDeployer.partialZipInstall(RdsDeployer.java:566)
    at org.tizen.common.rds.RdsDeployer.deploy(RdsDeployer.java:267)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.launch.TizenLaunchDelegate2.deployApplication(TizenLaunchDelegate2.java:783)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.launch.TizenLaunchDelegate2.launchApplicationForRun(TizenLaunchDelegate2.java:504)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.launch.TizenLaunchDelegate2.launch(TizenLaunchDelegate2.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.tizen.common.sdb.command.message.CommandErrorException: 
Error code: FATAL_ERROR
Error message: 
Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -q -r -t tpk -n com.au.heywatch
Management: Installation or uninstallation is not working temporarily.
```

P.S. I add "eclipse" tag because Tizen SDK is very clearly Eclipse based IDE. Using Tizen IDE 2.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch face applications(Web/native) are never installed as widgets. You cannot see them in app menu.

Reason:
Within your tizen-manifest.xml file in your project, you'll find below line there

```
<watch-application appid="org.tizen.watchsample" exec="watchsample" ambient-support="true">
```

which makes your app as **watch application** and these apps are known as watch faces because they will be used in setting as the main watch in gear.

And on **emulator**, you cannot change the watch face on the home screen. Hence, you won't be able to test your watch application that way.

Comment: @h22 - May I know the reason why it has been unmarked as the answer?

Comment: Your answer is no solution to the problem, nor it provides resources to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. My problem was certificate setup.

i followed there instructions: http://127.0.0.1:50224/help/topic/org.tizen.addon.certificate/html/dev_env/setting_author_certificate.htm
(link is from help and should work in browser when Tizen IDE is up, alternately you can go to Tizen IDE -> Help -> Help Content and search Certificate.

More specific: Distributor certificate i had was wrong (use the pass received by Samsung by email)

After fixing certificate, don't forget to right click your device in Connection Explorer and click *Permit to install applications*.