# Is Tizen 2.3.1 SDK usable for developing applications for Tizen watch?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

There is a Tizen SDK for wearables, downloadable from [here](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tools/download/release-notes/tizen-sdk-wearable/1.0.0-oct-02-2014?langredirect=1) by clicking the "Download" link on the top left. I try to create a "watch application" with the new project wizard, but I cannot run it inside the bundled emulator whatever I do. What I am doing wrong?

I have also tried the following beta version but all wearable options seem simply disabled (grayed) there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422594/installation-or-uninstallation-is-not-working-temporarily-error-when-trying-to/32430699#32430699) before you posted this question. And I have mentioned that you can't test **WatchFace** applications.

There is a difference between WatchFace app and normal watch apps.

WatchFace app/widget are generally shown on the main screen of a smartwatch which generally consist of information like time/date and other small details.

[image]

A normal watch application can be any app like a game app, utility app etc. And it can be tested on emulator. I have developed many apps using Tizen SDK 2.3.1

[image]

So, its better if you ask your questions specific to the type of app, so that other people can answer it.

Now coming to your question about the usability of Tizen SDK 2.3.1. Yes, the SDK is usable for developing watch app and WatchFace app. But you can only test the watch app on the emulator not the WatchFace app.

Comment: I confirm that regular applications (not "watch applications") indeed run no problem inside the emulator.

Comment: This is just ridiculous that a platform expect you to create content that cannot be tested. You can say what you want about Googl€, but Android Studio works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

"Watch application" that the New project wizard suggest to create is not an "application for the Tizen watch wearable" as one may assume. It is a special type of application that is more like screensaver, see @srkushwaha answer above. While these "watch applications for watches" indeed do not run in emulator, you do not need them  just for developing applications for the wristwatch device.

Instead, you need to select "UI application" and then either Basic UI application or Basic UI application EDC in the wizard menu. These applications can run on emulator without any difficulties.

[image]

Comment: The wearable category is for SmartWatch. Under that "Watch Application"(also known as watch face) is specific type of app which can only be tested on Original hardware.